# How to add item into a paragraphs

Tags: entities

I'm trying to create Paragraphs programatically, to store an Indesign File with the images linked to it, so I have my paragraph type with some fields

- field_indesign_file : (limited to one value)
- field_indesign_image : (illimited number of images)

Currently the creation is OK :

```
$paragraph = Paragraph::create([
  'type' => 'indesign',
  'field_indesign_file' => [
    'target_id' => $indesign->id(),
  ],
  'field_indesign_image' => [
    'target_id' => ${'image'.'3'}->id(),
  ],
]);
```

but I don't know in advance how many pictures I'll have attached to the indesign file, so Id' like to be able to add other values to the `field_indesign_image`.

I tried using

`$paragraph->field_indesign_image[LANGUAGE_NONE][1]['value'] = [ 
        'target_id' => ${'image'.'1'}->id() 
    ];`

and

`$paragraph->field_indesign_image->appendItem(
      [
        'target_id', ${'image'.'3'}->id()
      ]
    );`

but none of this method worked, I didn't find a lot of documentation and sometimes answers to other topic are a bit too complicated for me to understand since I'm a beginner at drupal 8.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I used a dynamic array

`$tabImage[]["target_id"]`

and inserted it

```
'field_indesign_rendition' => $tabImage,
```